# How to reference online workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Stuck on trying to reference a workbook which is on SharePoint.

I can use this to open the file:

```
Workbooks.Open("http://www.website.com/File.xlsx")
```

However, I want to execute without opening the file... is there a way to utilize that online workbook without opening?

I have tried (had to split out the string to multiple lines so it would show up like code):

```
Workbooks("http://www.website.com/File.xlsx")._
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

references and get errors if I try to add a website to the Workbooks section (typically run-time error 9, subscript out of range).  I have had the same error in trying to define the workbook beforehand:

```
Dim wbk as Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks("http://www.website.com/File.xlsx")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot read from a http-hosted workbook without opening it: there is nothing in the HTTP protocol which supports this (absent some kind of server-side coding).  What's the problem with opening the workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Short Answer:***

You need `Workbooks.Open(`" In order to analyze the workbook. 


***Solution Explanation:***

Using common language, `workbooks` is not a final instruction by itself, you need to specify what would you like to do with that object -kind of like talking in 3rd person-: "Workbook get opened" (Workbooks.Open) "Workbook add a new sheet"  (Workbooks.NewSheet) and such. As you may see, "Workbook" cannot work on itself, it is waiting an "order" -in this case events for it-. You may see a list of what can you do with workbook at the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx).


***Further explanation:***

Code itself cannot possible know what are you trying to do. You need to analyze the object as an Excel archive OR find a way that you perform it through the [webpage itself](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml) -which would be more complicated and you can only do so by IE since there are no [API](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/API.html) (API for short: a way to tell your code in one program to send commands to another one) for Excel for chrome or firefox to my knowledge-.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  I knew that I could define a local workbook as such, but was running into the issue for online workbooks.  Since this particular spreadsheet is on SharePoint, do you know offhand if there is an API to make VBA interface with that?  I will dig a bit on my own, but you already seem a bit knowledgeable in the matter and may be quicker than my reading.

Comment: Yeah, I have had the same problem as you -and have read overtime how I may surpass it- in the past, however, I have not found an effective way to do so and to be honest, there are many limitation in the sharepoint API for excel -for my workbooks due to many macros there, it is better to open it by Excel-. My workaround would be that you screenupdating=false in your code do your stuff and then close the workbook, sadly, there's no other way to achieve it -that could improve your code running speed at least-.

Comment: Thank you for the tip for screenupdating.  I will accept your answer; thanks for all of the information!